# React style row when onContextMenu is called

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

It's confusing when the :hover effect disappears when the ContextMenu is called and it's no longer clear which row the user is operating on, here are 2 images:

"tbody tr:hover" in action

[image]

ContextMenu is called, tr:hover is gone which is expected.

[image]

At first I thought it was trivial. Like adding this from another similar question.

```
<span className={`fa ${this.state.dropdownActive ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down'}`}></span>
```

So I started with a hook to catch the current row beign inspected

```
const [inspection, setInspection] = useState(null)

const inspectionStyle = ({ values }) => {
    // if(_.isEquals(values,inspection)){
        console.log("")
        console.log("A:"+values)
        console.log("B:"+inspection)
    if(values === inspection){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
...
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
    {page.map((row) => {
        prepareRow(row)
        return(
            <tr 
                className={`${inspectionStyle(row.values) ? 'inspected':''}`}
                onContextMenu={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    setShow(true)
                    setPoints({
                        x: e.pageX,
                        y: e.pageY
                    })
                    setInspection(row.values)
                }}
                {...row.getRowProps()}
            >
                {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                        {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </td>
                ))}                                    
            </tr>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

And logs look like this, no errors and "A" sits undefined:

[image]

Maybe I'm just taking the completely wrong approach. It's my first week with react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. But don't really know why it's working. Here are my changes, plus the css

[image]

1. Changed the return value from true/false to the actual className value to apply.
2. The check is `row === row.values`. If I change it to do a `row === row` it doesn't work, it has to be `row === row.values`. That's what I don't understand and it was just mere luck it worked.

---

```
const [show,setShow] = useState(false)

useEffect(() =>{
    // const handleClick = () => setShow(true)
    const handleClick = () => setShow(false)
    window.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
    if(!show)
        setInspection(null)
}, [show])

const [inspection, setInspection] = useState(null)

const inspectionStyle = ({ values }) => {
    // if(_.isEquals(values,inspection)){
        console.log("")
        console.log("A:"+values)
        console.log("B:"+inspection)
    if(inspection == null){
        return ''
    }
    if(values === inspection){
        // return true
        return 'inspected'
    }
    // return false
    return ''
}
...
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
    {page.map((row) => {
        prepareRow(row)
        return(
            <tr 
                className={inspectionStyle(row)}
                // className={`${inspectionStyle(row.values) ? 'inspected':''}`}
                onContextMenu={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    setShow(true)
                    setPoints({
                        x: e.pageX,
                        y: e.pageY
                    })
                    setInspection(row.values)
                }}
                {...row.getRowProps()}
            >
                {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                        {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </td>
                ))}                                    
            </tr>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

Trivial CSS:

```
.inspected{
  background-color: rgba(85, 96, 143, .75);
  color: white;
}

.inspected:hover{
  background-color: rgba(85, 96, 143, .75);
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
map((v, i) => ...
```

and check

```
i === inspection
```

in className.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).